# Extract char by sequence in a string vb 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a text in richtextbox1, I want to extract each 3 char of the string and so on, like:

```
richtextbox1.text = "It's Chrismas time"
```

Result, Sequence of 3 from Right to Left: "Isrmte"
Result, Sequence of 3 from Left to Right: "etmrsI"

How can I do it ?

Code can be in C# 2010. I will translate to vb.net 2010.

Answer (score 3):

How about `richtextbox1.text.Where((c, i) => i % 3 == 0)`?
Or RTL: `richtextbox1.text.Reverse().Where((c, i) => i % 3 == 0)`
In VB: `richtextbox1.text.Where(Function(c, i) i Mod 3 = 0)`

However, your example does not show extracting every third character -- your example ignores whitespace, which you might do this way:

```
text.Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Where(Function(c, i) i Mod 3 = 0)
```

To take the text and put it into another textbox, you could do this:

```
textbox2.text = String.Join("", textbox1.text
               .Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
               .Where(Function(c, i) i Mod 3 = 0))
```

Here's my test code copied directly from VS 2010:

```
    Dim text = "It's Chrismas time"
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("",
                    text.Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) _
                        .Where(Function(c, i) i Mod 3 = 0)))
```

Comment: Please say how you want to use the sequence, and I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad english but i will try to explain you, I have a richtextbox, with a long text inside, i want to take all 3 char until the end of the document, like in my example and put the result in another textbox.

Comment: I ABSOLUTLY WANT TO IGNORE whitespace :o)

Comment: your code give me "Impossible to cast an objet in type '<WhereIterator>d__0`1[System.Char]' in type 'System.String'.

Comment: He's using lambda syntax and extension methods from .Net 3.5+. It will do what you need, so long as you are not using .Net 2.0 or earlier.